# Defaut Character Set 'Unicode' in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-xp, x86

Does that mean i'm writting 64 bit code for x64 OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It means that `TCHAR` is mapped to `wchar_t` and all functions that take `TCHAR` or `LPTSTR` arguments are mapped to their Unicode variants.  For example `CreateWindow` is mapped to `CreateWindowW` and not to `CreateWindowA`.

And this is completely unrelated to CPU architecture.  You can write Unicode and Multibyte programs for 32 or 64 bit platforms.

If you want to build for x64, you need to go to add another platform in the Configuration Manager.  Here's the [how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: Can i explicitly use CreateWindowW without setting character encoding?

Comment: Yes, @User. You can explicitly call whatever function you want. The IDE setting, and the macros it defines, merely control the *default* API mode you get when you don't specify anything else.

Comment: Yes.  But `TCHAR` subsystem is designed to make switching between `char` and `wchar_t` almost seamless.  Still it's possible to mix `*A` and `*W` in one application in any proportion.

Comment: Your answer is correct, if talking about the `_UNICODE` macro, but this sounds like a setting in the IDE to decide which character set the *source files* are stored in... (UTF-8 or some local locale/codepage)

Answer (score 4):

No. Unicode is a character encoding, not a measure of CPU bits. You can write 64-bit code without using Unicode, and you can write 32-bit code while using Unicode. Neither requires the other. You can use both together if you want. You can also use neither.

Comment: I support this answer.  Essentially there is no connection between character encoding and machine word size.